# How to update keyboardType in Flutter (in the app)?

Tags: flutter

In normal Android development, you can change the keyboard type dynamically but I can't seem to find a way to do so in Flutter.

```dart
  TextInputType roomKeyboardType = TextInputType.text; // right on top of the build function
```

My custom form field:

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: FormBuilderTextField(
    attribute: "room",
    controller: widget.controllers[1],
    keyboardType: roomKeyboardType,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      filled: true,
      labelText: "Room",
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.black),
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard, color: Colors.black),
        onPressed: () {
          if (roomKeyboardType == TextInputType.text) {
            roomKeyboardType = TextInputType.number;
            return;
          }
          roomKeyboardType = TextInputType.text;
        },
      )),
      validators: [
        FormBuilderValidators.required(
          errorText: "Please enter the room number",
        ),
      ],
    ),
),
```

Right now, I have something that looks like this with a keyboard `IconButton` on the end of the form field. When I click on it, I expect my keyboard type to change, yet when I do, nothing happens. It's supposed to toggle between text and number keyboard types and it only stays on text as that's what I have the variable initially set to. The variable I know is changing, it's just the fact that Flutter probably isn't remaking the widget so the keyboard stays the same. Is there any way to get around this and am I able to change the `keyboardType` dynamically?
[image: Keyboard in flutter]

Answer (score 0):

you can change your keyboard type in TextFieldWidgets and many input widgets
like this:

```
   TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            hintText: '6 Digit-Code',
          ),
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I have edited my question. I'm aware of the fact I can change it like that, but I'm asking if I can do it inside of the app by pressing a button.

Comment: i don't think so you can change your keyboard type by pressing a button but what you can do is build  two widgets with different keyboard type and then change it onpressed

Comment: I posted a working example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60647450/3484824 I'm too lazy to test right now, but it'll be interesting to know if your suggestion @LalitRawat would prevent the closing of the keyboard before re-appearing with the new type, which my code does. Unlike Google Spreadsheet where the switch is immediate 