# Flutter, TextField, how to show up number firstly and able to change put text too

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

how to show up number firstly and able to change put text too?

Currenly what I did is

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number
```

This makes the first step work well.

However, it cannot be changed back to letters, only numbers are compulsory.

Answer (score 1):

`keyboardType: TextInputType.number` means your textField is `number only`.
You can track this with onChange method that do something to change `keyboardType` to text.

```dart
var myKeyboardType = TextInputType.number;

// your textFiled:
TextFiled(
  keyboardType: myKeyboardType,
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("Your rule")),
  ],
  onChanged: (text){
     if(text.length == 1) {// or other way 
         setState((){
           myKeyboardType = TextInputType.text;
           // may need to request focus again.
         }
     }
     else if (text.isEmpty) { //when user delete the number, change keyboard back.
       setState((){
           myKeyboardType = TextInputType.number;
           // may need to request focus again.
         }
     }
  },
),
```

You can use inputFormatters to limit user's input with `regexp`.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I want it to go straight back to the text keyboard from the numeric keypad without clicking any other button. At first, a number appears, but it should be able to return to the text keyboard on the same keyboard.

Comment: My answer edited.

Comment: there seems to be no such way. I don't know how many times I'm going to hit a number.  I tried to make it a bit easier to type the car number (sometimes letters come first instead of numbers) So, there seems to be a problem with the logic created using length. I can`t adopt it but vote it for information

Comment: For car number, my suggestion is, make a `car number keyboard` by self.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
         
              focusNode: widget._childnod,
              onChanged: (s) {
                if (s.length == 1) {
                  setState(() {
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    widget._inputType = TextInputType.text;
                 
                  });
               
                  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(widget._childnod);
                  });
                }
              },
              keyboardType: widget._inputType,
            ),
          )
```

Here we added future. delayed Because we need a small time gap to reopen the keyboard other wise it wouldn't work.**Here we don't use any button instead we use a delay**

```
  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(widget._childnod);
                  });
```

May like this:

[image]
**Sample Code**

```
void main() => runApp(
    MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: Changekeyboard())));

class Changekeyboard extends StatefulWidget {
  Changekeyboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  TextInputType _inputType = TextInputType.number;
  FocusNode? _childnod = FocusNode();

  @override
  _ChangekeyboardState createState() => _ChangekeyboardState();
}

class _ChangekeyboardState extends State<Changekeyboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                setState(() {
                  if (widget._inputType == TextInputType.number)
                    widget._inputType = TextInputType.text;
                  else
                    widget._inputType = TextInputType.number;
                });
              },
              child: Text(
                "Change type",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(

              focusNode: widget._childnod,
              onChanged: (s) {
                if (s.length == 1) {
                  setState(() {
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    widget._inputType = TextInputType.text;

                  });

                  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(widget._childnod);
                  });
                }
              },
              keyboardType: widget._inputType,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, so well documented appreciate it, But since Gold Rank doesn't know, there seems to be no such way. I don't know how many times I'm going to hit a number.  I tried to make it a bit easier to type the car number (sometimes letters come first instead of numbers) So, there seems to be a problem with the logic created using length. I can`t adopt it but vote it for information

Comment: you can use regex or custom logic in onchanged text.how was you vehicle number format

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions. use this package I think your almost problem solved